# How to update Real-time graph in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

Is there a Library that generate the effect of this page?

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/buy-rent-calculator.html?_r=2&abt=0002&abg=0

I assume (and I hope) that's JS but I dont know if it was made from scratch or if they are using any library in particular.

I wish that when people enter an amount or moves the bar, the graph is updated.

Do I have to recreate the graph each time the bar moves?

Hope you can help me

Comment: It certainly seems to be JavaScript. Which is great for you because you can just look at the source. That will tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data Driven Documents (D3)](http://d3js.org/)  is what the page in question is using.

[Knockout.JS](http://knockoutjs.com/)  is also a useful library for updating of elements in response to user input.

These are both javascript libraries.

Comment: If anything this post is really a comment.